# lxml - how to get xpath of HtmlElement?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Using an XML etree, it's possible to do:

`etree.getpath(element`

How would I do the same thing, but with HTML instead of XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_ElementTree` has a `getpath` method:

```
In [17]: import lxml.html as LH
In [18]: content = '<root><div id="pgbrk" ......>....Page Break....</div></root>'

In [19]: root = LH.fromstring(content)

In [20]: tree = root.getroottree()

In [21]: tree.getpath(root[0])
Out[21]: '/html/body/root/div'
```

Comment: lol lifesaver.  i was implementing this functionality myself.